# blob.doesBlobExist does not return values

Tags: node.js, azure-blob-storage

It might be a very stupid question but I need to ask;
I'm trying to check if a blob exists with doesBlobExist method from blobservice.

my code looks like this:

```
var blobexists;
var containerNamesArray[.....,....,...,..]
for (var i = 0; i < containerNamesArray.length; i++) {
    
    
    blobService.doesBlobExist(containerNamesArray[i], "path/something.json", function (error, result) {
        if (!error) {
            if (result.exists) {
                blobexists= result.exists
                console.log(blobexists) //this prints values

                return(blobexists)
                
            } else {

                blobexists= result.exists
                return(blobexists)
            }
            
        }
    });

console.log(blobexists) //this returns null
}
```

Now if I do console.log inside the if(!error), I get the value of the result, if i assign result.exists to blobexists, return the value, and try to print in in the for or outside the for it says that blobexistsis null.

Why return is not letting me returning the value to the global var?

Answer (score 0):

> Why return is not letting me returning the value to the global var?

This is because your `blobService.doesBlobExist` method is executing asynchronously. So a request is sent to check for the blob's existence and the response is awaited however your `console.log(blobexists)` is executed almost immediately after calling the `doesBlobExist` method.

Comment: Hi Gaurava, thank you for your answer, should I use await somewhere in an asynchronous function? do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I would actually recommend using [`BlueBird Promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird) library and put the entire loop inside a promise.